# What is iTunes Radio's skip limit?

Tags: itunes-match, itunes-radio

Pandora, Spotify Radio, and other music/radio streaming services usually have a limit on the number of skips allowed in a set amount of time. Does iTunes Radio have a similar limit, and if so, what are its conditions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's 6 song skips per hour for each station.

I also have iTunes Match turned on and I'm still limited to 6 skips.

Comment: Same here, which is extremely frustrating. I had thought being an iTunes Match subscriber removed the skip limit.

Answer (score 5):

I have observed a skip limit being enforced - after 5 rapid skips on some of the canned stations, one is left. This matches [Apple's list of common questions](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS5181) that states 6 skips per channel in an hour is the current limit.

[image: Skip notification on iTunes radio]

Also, the skip control seems to be disabled for some narrated tracks like the Guest DJ when the artist is speaking. There's nothing in the legal terms about iTunes Radio nor wording I can see in the iTunes Match section covering this.

- http://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/us/terms.html#SALE

Answer (score 2):

If you are an itunes match subscriber to get unlimited skips:

1. locate and click on Match on the top bar (where it says "songs albums artists etc")
2. either subscribe if your subscription has ended or hit "Done" at the bottom right of the screen
3. play a different station for 10 seconds and then go back to the original one
4. enjoy your unlimited skips!

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple walkaround for this, just change the channel and come back to the original one, refreshes the number of skips ;)